# Merger of Early Modern English 'ir' with 'ur' and 'er'+'ear'

Tags: phonology, phonetics, historical-change, early-modern-english, language-evolution

Before /r/, /ɪ/ merged with either /ʊ/ or /ɛ/, depending on context. After labials (plus clusters of labials and /l/) and alveolar stops (like in bird and dirt), the result was /ʊ/ (shown, among other spellings, by 'durt', which was an old spelling variant of 'dirt'), which then became /ʌ/ in most dialects, while /ɛ/ is the result elsewhere. They both eventually merged before /r/ into a single central vowel in most modern English dialects. While /ʊ/ can be expected after labials, it being the result after alveolar stops too is unexpected. What are the articulatory and perception bases for the merger of /ɪ/ into either /ʊ/ or /ɛ/ before /r/?

Comment: In American rhotic Englishes, at least, /r/ is rounded.

Comment: Can you give examples of more of these (beyond 'bird' and 'dirt')? Also, name some of the dialects in 'most' and 'elsewhere'.

Comment: The conditions on the development of 'ir' were from those links: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/ (section NURSE mergers) and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects. As for most, the first one is every variety of English besides those of northern England and some of Ireland, the second is every dialect minus Scottish, some Irish, and Cajun. The elsewhere refers to development of Early Modern English 'ir' rather than dialects.

Comment: Also, while prevocalic /r/ is rounded in those English varieties using alveolar and retroflex approximant /r/'s, postvocalic /r/'s seem to have little to no rounding in rhotic dialects (it's a moot point in non-rhotic dialects for obvious reasons). Complicating things, the shift from /ɪ/ to /ʊ/ after labials (and labial+/l/ clusters) and alveolar stops (and before /r/) happened when postvocalic /r/ was still a trill or a tap.